# Web Audio API. Play sound on click of button

Tags: api, html5-audio

I am a complete novice with HTML5 and coding for that matter. I have been trying to get to grips with the web audio API. I want a sound to play at a click of a button. I used a tutorial posted on HTML5Rocks, but cannot get it to work. I have tried to use jfiddle to help me troubleshoot, but to no avail.

here is my code:
http://jsfiddle.net/ue8WP/

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
function playsound()
{    
    var filepath='sounds/'+....+'.mp3'; //example
    var audio = new Audio();   
    audio.src = filepath;
    audio.controls = true;
    audio.autoplay = true;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simplified version of your code that should work fine. You only need to load some other sample sound, since there is a problem with fetching the one you provided (not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin).

http://jsfiddle.net/WB6Pw/3/

Comment: as @MrRioku noted "XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://tonycuffe.com/mp3/tail%20toddle.mp3. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://fiddle.jshell.net' is therefore not allowed access."